# Two nfs exports from different servers mounted on the same mount point

Tags: linux, mount, nfs

Recently found these lines on my test server:

```
<some  IPV4>:/zebra on /zebra type nfs (rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=262144,wsize=262144,namlen=255,hard,nolock,proto=tcp,port=2051,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=10.126.84.153,mountvers=3,mountport=5004,mountproto=udp,local_lock=all,addr=10.126.84.153)
<some IPV4>://zebra on /zebra type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.0,rsize=262144,wsize=262144,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=172.17.1.20,local_lock=none,addr=10.48.28.115)
```

Now I have a couple of questions:

1. Why Linux allows mount different exports from the same mountpoint
2. If I do for example `ls /zebra` on which export will be listed?
3. Can I `umount` from specific server, for example `10.126.84.153`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Because any directory is valid mountpoint
2. The content of the **latest mounted** share will be listed
3. AFAIK you cannot. The latest mount will be unmounted firstly

   ```
   # mkdir testmount  
   # mount --bind /bin/ testmount/  
   # mount --bind /usr/bin/ testmount/  
   # mount |grep testmount  
   /bin on /testmount type none (rw,bind)  
   /usr/bin on /testmount type none (rw,bind)  
   # umount testmount/  
   # mount |grep testmount  
   /bin on /testmount type none (rw,bind)  
   # umount testmount/  
   # mount |grep testmount  
   #
   ```